# Assigning value to new column for 'other' responses

Tags: r

I'm collecting survey data through Google Forms and my dependent variable includes different types of services that are used as well as an 'other' option where respondents can specify other services that are not listed. These responses are exported in one column and separated by semicolons which looks like this:

| ID | Service Use |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Home care;transportation;[custom text] |
| 2 | None of these services have been used |

I've created columns for each of the services with 0/1 (yes/no) values to indicate use/non-use but am struggling to figure out how to do this with the 'other' group as it will contain custom text. I know that grepl can be used to assign values based on whether a column includes a certain string of text and have used this to separate out the specified variables:

```
data$homecare <- ifelse(grepl("Home care", data$serviceuse), 1, 0)
```

So that my dataframe now looks like this:

| ID | Home care | Transportation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

But is there a way to apply a similar function in the way that I need for custom text?

What I need is a new column for 'other' so that it looks like this:

| ID | Home care | Transportation | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I was thinking if I could check whether there is an unspecified string in the column (i.e., if it doesn't match the other strings provided) then I could assign a value to the new column indicating that it is present. However, I have no idea if that's even possible or where to start.

Comment: After trawling the internet some more I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349105/need-help-processing-multiple-response-strings-from-a-google-form-using-r)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer_delim()` to separate out all the different selections, then `pivot_wider` (with `values_fn = length` and `values_fill = 0`) to swing it to wide format.

I am extending your sample table to add in different "custom texts", and creating a key for the pre-defined values (`keyvals`)

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID Service_Use
1   'Home care;transportation;abc'
2   'Home care;def'
3   'None of these services have been used'", header = TRUE)

keyvals <- c("Home care", "transportation")
```

Now you can use `separate_longer_delim`, then `mutate`, then `pivot_wider`. If you dont want the "None"  column, you can add a `select` on the end:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Service_Use, delim = ";") %>%
  mutate(Service_Use = case_when(
    Service_Use %in% "None of these services have been used" ~ "None",
    !(Service_Use %in% keyvals) ~ "Other",
    TRUE ~ Service_Use)
    ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Service_Use, values_from = Service_Use, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-None)
```

Output:

```
#      ID `Home care`  transportation Other
# 1     1           1               1     1
# 2     2           1               0     1
# 3     3           0               0     0
```

Though for many analytic and visual purposes, you may want to leave it in long format:

```
df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Service_Use, delim = ";") %>%
  mutate(Service_Use = case_when(
    Service_Use %in% "None of these services have been used" ~ "None",
    !(Service_Use %in% keyvals) ~ "Other",
    TRUE ~ Service_Use)
    ) 

#   ID    Service_Use
# 1  1      Home care
# 2  1 transportation
# 3  1          Other
# 4  2      Home care
# 5  2          Other
# 6  3           None
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the first part where the variables are already defined but only seems to work for custom text if it's the same in every instance. It still doesn't combine all of those custom answers into one 'other' group.

Comment: @sionach see edit, that should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  # create row identifier (needed later for pivot_wider):
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  # split rows by ";":
  separate_rows(ID_Service_Use, sep = ";") %>%
  # change all values other than "home care" and "transportation" to "other"
  # (?i) makes the match case-insensitive:
  mutate(ID_Service_Use = ifelse(!str_detect(ID_Service_Use, "(?i)home care|transportation"),
                                 "other", ID_Service_Use)) %>%
  # cast wider and count occurrences of values:
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID_Service_Use, values_from = ID_Service_Use, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  # remove obsolete column
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  `Home care` transportation other
        <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
1           1              1     1
2           1              0     1
3           0              0     1
```

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame(ID_Service_Use = c('Home care;transportation;abc',
                                    'Home care;def',
                                    'None of these services have been used'))
```